# What does "subtract A to B" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, mathematics

I am a little confused about this specially when answering arithmetic problems. Help me with this: what does "subtract A to B" mean?

1. A-B
2. B-A

Comment: Subtract A from B is B - A. Subtract A to B is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you found this sentence, but it's not correct English.

You *add* one number *to* another one (in that case, the order doesn't matter). But you *subtract* a number (*A*) *from* another one (*B*), which means *B* – *A*. Your source used the wrong preposition. See e.g. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subtract) for sample sentences.